# Mock view returned by FindView

Tags: model-view-controller, moq

I want to mock (using MOQ) view returned by Findview method as shown below, so that view is not null:

```
if ((ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, masterName)).View == null)
            {
                viewName = SomeViewName;
            }
```

i have mocked viewengine like this following an e.g. online:

```
var mockViewEngine = new Mock<IViewEngine>();
        // Depending on what result you expect you could set the searched locations
        // and the view if you want it to be found
        Mock<IView> view = new Mock<IView>();
        var result = new ViewEngineResult(new[] { "location1", "location2" });

        // Stub the FindView method
        mockViewEngine
            .Setup(x => x.FindView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), false))
            .Returns(result);

        // Use the mocked view engine instead of WebForms
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(mockViewEngine.Object);
```

but when i run test it gives me this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use It.IsAny < bool >  instead of just false when setup FindView method.